# NOLOCK error when attaching databases

Tags: sql-server-2012

One of my servers went down and I've had to move all my databases to another server. I want to use the "attach" functionality in SQL Server 2012 (these databases are SQL Server 2005).

For some reason I am getting a `NOLOCK` error on most of the databases when trying to attach them:

> Could not continue scan with NOLOCK due to data movement.
>   
> Could not open new database 'db'. CREATE DATABASE is aborted.
>   
> File activation failure. The physical file name "D:\db\xxxx_log.ldf" may be incorrect.
>   
> New log file 'C:\db\xxxx_log.ldf' was created. 
>   
> (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 601)

Comment: Well, in Management Studio have you set Tools > Options > SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL > READ UNCOMMITTED? I don't think that would affect an attach operation but who knows, I don't know why else you would get this error message during an attach. Did you use the UI to perform the attach, or `CREATE DATABASE ... FOR ATTACH_REBUILD_LOG;`, or some other method?

Comment: Hi, I used the UI. Just went to the main DB and clicked "Attach". It's happening on most of the databases.

Comment: Please check the option I mentioned, and change it from READ UNCOMMITTED if that's what it's currently set to. It's under Tools > Options > Query Execution > SQL Server > Advanced

Comment: Nope, same error I am afraid

Comment: [Read this](http://dba.stackexchange.com/a/42807/1186). If it doesn't help, your MDF file may be corrupt (though I will agree this is a strange symptom). Hopefully you've taken backups and this MDF isn't your backup. Why do you not have the .ldf files too? Was SQL Server shut down before these files were detached? Where did they come from?

Comment: Hi, I have both the MDF files and the LDF files. For some reason SQL doesnt like it when I try and attach both.

Comment: When I try and attach the MDF and LDF files: Could not continue scan with NOLOCK due to data movement.
Converting database 'xx' from version 690 to the current version 706.
Database 'xx' running the upgrade step from version 690 to version 691. (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 601)

Comment: Still sounds like they're corrupt (likely SQL Server wasn't cleanly shut down).

Comment: Yes, I would agree with that. I get this error when running the attach command: File activation failure. The physical file name "D:\db\xxx_log.ldf" may be incorrect.
The log cannot be rebuilt because there were open transactions/users when the database was shutdown, no checkpoint occurred to the database, or the database was read-only. This error could occur if the transaction log file was manually deleted or lost due to a hardware or environment failure.

Comment: Yep. Get a backup, this may not end well.

Comment: This is not a programming question. You may get more help by posting on dba.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 0):

Judging by the comments above, this database is well and truly broken, there are ways to recover it, one of which is detailed here:

[Re-attaching, and fixing a SUSPECT database](http://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/paul/creating-detaching-re-attaching-and-fixing-a-suspect-database/)

But the problem with this is that you can never be sure what state the data is in, it is most likely transactionally inconsistent which will most likely cause you pain later on if you continue trying to use this.

Best thing to do is if you have a backup, restore that instead.